# Rails 5.0 -> 5.1 issue: has_many through with custom lambda generates invalid query by including scope block twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have associations like:

```
class TransportOrder < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :invoice_lines, as: :invoicable

  has_many :transport_invoices,
    -> { where("invoices.id <> 0") },  # Simplified condition for this question.
    through: :invoice_lines,
    source: :invoice,
    source_type: "BuyerInvoice"
end

class InvoiceLine < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :invoice, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :invoicable, polymorphic: true
end
```

On Rails 5.0, running `TransportOrder.joins(:transport_invoices).to_a` worked fine.

But after upgrading to Rails 5.1, I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
  PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "invoices"
  LINE 1: ...s"."invoicable_id" = "transport_orders"."id" AND (invoices.i...
                                                               ^
  : SELECT "transport_orders".* FROM "transport_orders"
    INNER JOIN "invoice_lines"
    ON "invoice_lines"."invoicable_id" = "transport_orders"."id"
       AND (invoices.id <> 0)
       AND invoice_lines"."invoice_type" = 'BuyerInvoice'
       AND "invoice_lines"."invoicable_type" = 'TransportOrder'
    INNER JOIN "invoices"
    ON "invoices"."id" = "invoice_lines"."invoice_id"
       AND (invoices.id <> 0)
```

The issue seems to be that the scope block `-> { where("invoices.id <> 0") }` is applied not only when joining `invoices`, but also when joining `invoice_lines`. But at that point, we haven't yet joined in `invoices`.

So the first `AND (invoices.id <> 0)` in the SQL above should not be there – it wasn't there on Rails 5.0, and it breaks the query.

I also tried adding a `InvoiceLine.belongs_to :transport_invoice, -> { where("invoices.id <> 0") }, …` association, moving the scope block there, but I get the same issue.

Any ideas on how to fix this without having to write a lot more custom SQL?

Comment: I realised we didn't strictly need the scope block in this case, so my "fix" was just to skip it and change the logic a bit to accommodate that. If that hadn't worked, my plan was to add a named scope or class method that I would instead of `joins(:my_association)`. And add comments to point out that the code was duplicated between that scope and the association, and to keep them in sync. That would give me more control over the resulting SQL, to avoid this issue.

Comment: Was able to reproduce this on 6.0 as well, so opened an issue: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/40109

Answer (score 1):

We were able to work around this one by rewriting the code to skip the condition entirely, but then we ran into a similar issue and "solved" it like this:

```
has_many :invoices_without_the_condition,
  through: :invoice_lines,
  source: :invoice,
  source_type: "BuyerInvoice"

scope :joins_invoices, -> { joins(:invoices_without_the_condition).where("invoices.id <> 0") }
```

And then doing e.g. `TransportOrder.joins_invoices.more_scopes_here.to_a`.

I hate it, but it seems to work… :)